# PHP - Recursive adding subcategories

Tags: php, recursion, nested

Though it may seem simple, I've been struggling with this case for days and I've been not able to find a solution. I explain it on the following lines:

## What I have

I've got two arrays: one with the order of the *categories* and another one with the values of those *categories*. Something as follows:

```
$orders = 
    [
        {
            category: 3
        },
        {
            category: 8
        }
    ];

$values = 
    {
        3: [
            {
                id: 1,
                value: 'Value 1' 
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                value: 'Value 2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                value: 'Value 3'
            }
        ],
        8: [
            {
                id: 6,
                value: 'Value 6' 
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                value: 'Value 7'
            }
        ]
    };
```

As you can see, there are 2 *categories* but they can be more (in fact, up to 10 of them).

**EDIT**

The relation between `result` and the other variables is that, as you can see, category 3 has values with `id` 1, 2 and 3. So, as the category 3 is the first in the `order` array, I need to get every category inside category 3.

So, as a explaining sample, category 3.1 (as well as 3.2 and 3.3) should have inside subcategories 8.6 and 8.7.

## What I need

I need to make them subcategories each one of the previous one, taking into account the order. So, as the order is first category number 3 and then, category number 8, foreach value of category 3 there must be inside all the values of category 8 (and so on, if more categories were added, each of the values of next category would be under category number 8).

So what I need to have is the following result:

```
 $result = 
    [
        {
            category: {id: 1}, // Category 3 first value
            subcategories: [
                {
                    category: {id: 6} // Category 8 first value
                },
                {
                    category: {id: 7} // Category 8 second value
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            category: {id: 2}, // Category 3 second value
            subcategories: [
                {
                    category: {id: 6} // Category 8 first value
                },
                {
                    category: {id: 7} // Category 8 second value
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            category: {id: 3}, // Category 3 third value
            subcategories: [
                {
                    category: {id: 6} // Category 8 first value
                },
                {
                    category: {id: 7} // Category 8 second value
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

## What I've tried

I can't write all the approaches that I've tried, but I cannot seem to find a suitable solution for this.

I've tried recursive functions (and I think it's the correct way to implement this) but all I can come with is a *'Stack call exceeded'* like error.

## Aclarations

Data source is open so it's suitable for changes. However, I would like to keep it this way because there are future implications with this structure - though if it's necessary, they can change too.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the `$result` object under the "What I need" part. How does `$orders` translate into `$result`? I don't even see category 8 there.

Comment: I've editted the question (under What I have) so it is clearer. Thank you for your time and sorry for making it so confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it!

Here is the code I'm using that, at least for the moment, works (and I can add as many `orders` as I want):

```
$result = array();
$objtoadd = array();

for($i = sizeof($orders)-1; $i >= 0; $i--){

    $objtoadd[$i] = array();
    $objtoadd[$i]['subcategories'] = array();

    $act_gr = $orders[$i];
    $obj;

    foreach($values[$act_gr->category] as $sub){

        $obj = array();
        $obj['category'] = $sub;

        if(isset($objtoadd[$i+1]) && sizeof($objtoadd[$i+1]['subcategories']) > 0) $obj['subcategories'] = $objtoadd[$i+1]['subcategories'];

        $objtoadd[$i]['subcategories'][] = $obj;

    }

    if($i === 0 && isset($objtoadd[$i]) && isset($objtoadd[$i]['subcategories'])) $result = $objtoadd[$i]['subcategories'];

}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Thank you everyone for your time and answers, as well as for your patience!